# Speech_recognition not working in VSCode(python)

Tags: visual-studio-code, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm trying to finish a UI which prompts the User with the Speech-to-Text on the side of the screen but when I try to record audio in VSCode the microphone does not pick up noise.  There is no problem with the mic when I run the code in Idle. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: How exactly do you try to record audio with VS Code? Can you provice more information?

Comment: @moosehead i record audio using the speech_recognition library an using my microphone my calling speech_recognition.Microphone() there is no error with the way i use the microphone because this method works in IDLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently VSCode is not asking for mic permissions. For some it seems to work if you start code from the terminal via `code`. I got it to work following this advice from here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/3254

```
open vscode
open command pallete (command shift p)
shell command install code in path ( is an option)
get them to run that
close vscode
then from bash type code
permissions then get asked when you execute requiring microphone ( or it did when i ran a python file needing it)
```